# Using GLM with Poisson or Negative binomial with Count data

Tags: r, plot, glm

I am currently trying to run a glm for data in R and I am trying to understand if I am using the best possible model.

My data are count data for survival of four species of flies over time, with species, sex, density and day (I repeated my survival count every 5 days) as different factors.

My code looks like this:

```
survival <- cbind(Dead,Alive)
model1 <- glm (survival ~ Species*density*Sex*day,
      data = DataM5, family = quasibinomial)
car::Anova(model1, Type = "III")
plot(model1)
```

My QQ plots have heavy tails and my  residuals vs fitted plots look very skewed to the right. I understand this as meaning that my variance is not normally distributed (Forgive me if I don't have this right, I am battling to understand Stats but trying my best), and if this is so, then the assumptions of my glm are violated. From what I have read I think I need to use either a Poisson distribution or a negative binomial distribution but I can't seem to get either of them to work. Is this the correct approach? And if it is how do I get it to work in R?

[image: QQ Plot]

[image: Residual vs Fitted Plot]

Comment: This question appears to be more about statistics than R programming. As a result I've flagged it to be moved to Cross Validated

Answer (score 0):

1. A poisson regression with a log link function is usually used to model count response
2. Species*density*Sex*day, you are including interaction of all your covariates, think about whether it is really necessary or not. By using this model, you will probably have a model that overfits the data.
3. Poisson regression is one of the GLM(s), but the residuals are not assumped to be normally distributed.